# Track notifications limit usage

Tags: limits, notification, push-notification

We use two ways to trigger push notifications - APEX and flow/process builder. There are limits to the number of these push notifications (10 000 per hour). Is there a way to monitor the current usage of the limit, ideally for both, but preferably for flow/process builder triggered notifications?

Comment: I am not sure about any monitoring services for `Custom Notification`, but you could just insert a new record just after custom notification is triggered via apex, flow / process builder and then just run a report on that.